# How to figure out which field has changed in a table? in C# with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, user-controls, field, tracking

In a table of fields **a, b, c, d, ...,** then **user x** changes the value of **c, d,** all field values ​​**override** and the **values ​​of c and d are changed**, the history I want From this system is that :

**User x** has changed the value of **c and d at the same time**, displaying both the new and the old values, and the same for other users.

If the user just edited but no changes were made to the fields, **nothing would have happened**.

And in order to figure out which fields have changed now, **all fields have to be conditioned**, **or is there a library in C# to figure out which fields have changed now?**

If this is a library an example of it is a great help.

Comment: It's not user changing values in database, it's your software write changes and during this step you can check what was changed.

Comment: You could implement on your DB an history table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ChangeTracker class for discovery what was changed. You will need to use reflection to find the properties names of each modified entity.

```
foreach (var entry in db.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(entry => entry.State == EntityState.Added || entry.State == EntityState.Modified))
{
    // Gets all properties from the changed entity by reflection.
    foreach(var entityProperty in entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        var propertyName = entityProperty.Name;
        var currentValue = entry.Property(propertyName).CurrentValue;
        var originalValue = entry.Property(propertyName).OriginalValue;
    }
}
```

You can find more information about the ChangeTracker in this site: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/change-tracking-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: This answer has lot of issues. It does not support columns mapped to fields, non public properties, custom valuecomparers....

Comment: I'm seeing OriginalValue give me the CurrentValue for some reason (in SaveChanges())

Comment: Have you set the property with the same value it already had?

Answer (score 2):

I have done this many times. It is much easier to implement on the database side with a trigger.

```
create table Customer
(
    CustomerId integer Identy(1,1) primary key,
    CustomerFirstName nvarhar(25),
    CustomerLastName nvarchar(25),
    CustomerAdd1 nvarchar(50),
    CustomerAdd2 nvarchar(50)
)

create table ChangeAudit
(
    AuditId integer Identy(1,1) primary key
    ChangeDt datetime,
    ChangeTable nvarchar(50),
    ChangeField nvarchar(50),
    OldValue nvarchar(max),
    NewValue nvarchar(max),
    ChangedBy nvarchar(50)
)

create trigger CustomerAudit on Customer
after update, insert
as
begin
    if update(CustomerFirstName)
    begin
        insert into ChangeAudit(ChangeDt,ChangeTable,ChangeField,OldValue,NewValue,ChangedBy)
        select getdate(),'Customer', 'CustomerFirstName',d.CustomerFirstName,i.CustomerFirstName,SUSER_SNAME()
        from Customer c,
        inner join inserted i on t.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
        inner join deleted d on t.CustomerId = d.CustomerId
    end

    if update(CustomerLastName)
    begin
        insert into ChangeAudit(ChangeDt,ChangeTable,ChangeField,OldValue,NewValue,ChangedBy)
        select getdate(),'Customer', 'CustomerLastName',d.CustomerLastName,i.CustomerLastName,SUSER_SNAME()
        from Customer c,
        inner join inserted i on t.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
        inner join deleted d on t.CustomerId = d.CustomerId
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use EF as intended then you can find most in the changetracker before you commit.

```
_entities.ChangeTracker.Entries()
            .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified)
            .ToList();
```

EF don't do a database call unless something actually is updated

Comment: How do I get the name and field value from this list?